# Not able to connect AWS QuickSight to AWS Athena: "TooManyBuckets"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create a new dataset in AWS QuickSight and connecting it to AWS Athena. But the validation is failing with the following error.

```
[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. You have attempted to create more buckets than allowed (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TooManyBuckets;
```

Does QuickSight creates a new bucket in S3 for creating new dataset?

If yes then my bucket capacity is full (100 buckets are already there in S3).
Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Amazon Athena saves output to an Amazon S3 bucket. If you have not specified an output bucket, it might be trying to create another one. You can try changing the Output settings in Athena. However, you really should delete some buckets or request more buckets. See: [AWS service quotas - AWS General Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have specified the output bucket location for Athena. Whenever I run the query, the result and metadata gets saved in that location. But do we need to provide output bucket for Aws-Quicksight as well. I am exploring a way (if any) to specify output bucket in quicksight too, but no luck yet. Please let me know if you are aware of it!!